# Can you explain difference between StrictMock and Partialmock?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

As I am using RhinoMocks version 3.6 and as I am not using Record-Replay and as I do not call Verify methods for asserting on mocks;

Can you explain what is the difference between very simply?

```
MockRepository.GenerateMock()
MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock()
MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock()
```

Note: I use .GenerateMock all the time to create my mocks and I assert method calls by providing arguments expectation already.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The differences are [explained in this article](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Introduction.ashx#Mocks,DynamicMocksandPartialMocksohmy!:)

If you create no expectations on a `StrictMock`, and a method gets called on the mock, an exception will be thrown.

If you create no expectations on a `PartialMock`, and a method gets called on the mock, nothing special happens.  If that mock derives from a base class, the call bleeds through to the existing base implementation.

There is also something called a `DynamicMock`.  If you create no expectations on a `DynamicMock`, and a method gets called on the mock, a stub method is called.  If there was a return value, a default value (e.g. `null` or `0`) is returned.

`GenerateMock` I believe creates a `DynamicMock`.

Ayende chose this default because he recommends an ideal of only using `DynamicMock` and `Stub`.  `StrictMock` creates brittle tests, and usually violates the concept of only verifying one behavior per test.

See this article: http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino%20Mocks%203.5.ashx#CreateMockisdeprecated,replacedbyStrictMockTheuseofStrictMockisdiscouraged

I've also seen him say that it is useful to start with strict mocks, and work your tests back down to dynamic mocks/stubs once you're comfortable with how your code-under-test is behaving.  No link for that tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to add that "the use of Strict Mock is discouraged" by the words of Ayende.
http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#CreateMockisdeprecated,replacedbyStrictMockTheuseofStrictMockisdiscouraged

He says:

> Strict mocks will fail if something that is not expected will happen
>   to them. In the long run, this means that any change to the code under
>   test can break your tests, even if the change has nothing to do with
>   what you are actually testing in this specific test.
>
> I encourage the use of stubs and dynamic mocks instead.